# Using a jQuery function inside a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a PHP array of elements

Now I would like to create a link or a button for each of the array elements, when clicked, the array value should appear inside a specific div.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$array = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
foreach($array as $element) {
?>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="showElement"><?php echo $element; ?></a><br />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showElement").click( function() {
            $("#hot").append('<?php echo $element; ?><br />');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div id="hot"></div>
```

This just doesn't work the way I'd like it to. It displays the separate links for each of the array elements, but when I click on the first one it just displays all the three array elements, instead of just the intended one. The other two links do nothing.

Any help would be appreciated guys, my approach may even be completely the wrong way to do it, so please lead me to the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: Reusing the same `id` for multiple elements is not allowed. If you need to pass data from PHP to JS, use `<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>` instead of `'<?php echo $value; ?>'` (mind the quotes).

Comment: Use either PHP or JavaScript to generate your data. You can't mix serverside and clientside languages like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
<?php
$array = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
$i=0;
foreach($array as $element) {
    echo '<a href="#" class="showElement" id="showElement'.$i.'">'.$element.'</a><br />';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $target = $('#target');
    $(".showElement").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $target.append( $(this).text() );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is point of adding inline `onclick` when you are using jQuery to create click handler? Mixing obtrusive and unobtrusive script makes no sense

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, I wrote down the OP onclick="return false;" but could remove it as well, thanks

Comment: return `false` from the jQuery clcik handler though

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you want to achieve actually, but you should separate concerns [i.e. don't let php mess with js directly at least].

Consider injecting your values via `data-*` attributes, and retrieve them later via jQuery like this:

```
<?php foreach($array as $element): ?>

    <a href="#" class="yourClass" data-value="<?php echo $element; ?>"><?php echo $element; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<div id="target"></div>

<script>

$(function(){

    var $target = $('#target')

    $('.yourClass').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault()

        $target.append( $(this).data('value') )

    })

})

</script>
```

Remember then that `id` attribute should be unique, and cannot be repeated throughout DOM.

Comment: I upvoted you as the most reasonable answer, but you're introducing an unnecessary global variable `$target`, missing ending semicolons and not escaping `$element`.

Comment: `$target` is cached in order not to require it on every click [though I can declare it local, yep], ending [semicolons are optional](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/), and about escaping you are right, but this example is so vanilla that I didn't want to go further - I won't attach stuff to the DOM if content would need escaping. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Didn't quite work for me... I'm very bad at javascript and jquery, maybe there is something I'm missing. Sorry.

Comment: @AhmedSa'eed What *didn't work*? Got any errors in the console? I could have made a typo - write `console.log( $(this).data() )` after `e.preventDefault()` and check the console [you can find it in Chrome under Developer Tools].

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$array = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
foreach($array as $element) {
?>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="showElement-<?php echo $element; ?>"><?php echo $element; ?></a><br />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showElement-<?php echo $element; ?>").click( function() {
            $("#hot").append('<?php echo $element; ?><br />');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div id="hot"></div>
```

The problem is that you're binding the same id's to your append function. I've changed your id names. You can simply change them using

```
$("#showElement-<?php echo $element; ?>")
```

So they get a different id name anyway.